# Magento 1.9.2 Upgraded to magento 2 via admin panel

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I was reading the upgrade guide - but had the idea to try the upgrade via Magento connect. but is there any chance to update via admin panel

Comment: FYI: There is never a compelling reason to upgrade via Connect. You are always better to upgrade in a dev environment where you can control all the files.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot update to Magento2 using admin interface or magento connect.

Magento 2 has backward incompatible changes to code and database, so magento team developed [data migration tools](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce) that allow migrate data form 1.x to 2.x version, but it have commandline interface.