# Can i still use magento 1.9 module/theme at magento 2.0

Tags: magento-2.0

Simple question as title, Can i still use magento 1.9 module/theme at magento 2.0? Is magento 2.0 a completely new system and not compatible with 1.9?

Comment: step 1. migration major to major version isn't a thing, it's a process. let that sink in. and work on finding an answer.

Comment: There is no magic here, the Mage will need to remove his shirt and start engaging in actual physical labor. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87007/magento-1-9-2-upgraded-to-magento-2-via-admin-panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use Magento 1.x extensions and design themes with Magento 2 without code refactoring.
There is the official code migration tool which can help the developers to migrate theirs extensions and design themes: https://github.com/magento/code-migration
But the tools is for experienced developers only.

Answer (score 2):

The architecture of Magento 1.9x is entirely different than Magento 2.x so technically it's not possible to migrate a Magento 1.9.x to 2.x without actually changing the entire theme architecture. Magento 2.x is not backward compatible with Magento 1.9.x so it's NOT possible.