# How I can migrate Magento 1.9.2 modules to Magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, extensions, third-party-module

Is there any helpful links or guide to migrating Magento 1.9.2 modules/extensions to the new version (i.e. 2.x)?

Any automated solution or instructions set would be helpful.

Would be helpful to make compatibility with Magento 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90636/can-i-still-use-magento-1-9-module-theme-at-magento-2-0), There is the official code migration tool which can help the developers to migrate their extensions and design themes: https://github.com/magento/code-migration. I haven't tried yet... but this should help you to start.

Answer (score 1):

Custom code used by your Magento 1 store is compatible with Magento 2 in most cases. The code will require either rewriting or migrating.

Magento offers code migration tools that can help with this process. Note that due to platform differences, the migration output requires additional work to make sure it can be successfully installed in a Magento 2 store.

Learn more about the [Code Migration Toolkit.](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

**Optional**

[Unirgy convertm1m2](https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2)

Comment: hi @Rafael, I want to migrate only all data, is any free modules are available? Using cli with default migration tool, i migrated all data successfully, looking for free module to migrate with user interface.

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar, Uber themes company has a great free module for it using a GUI.

Comment: I have checked ubertheme module, it doesn't work for 2.3.1, is any other modules available?

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Magento 1, Magento 2 can bring about better design, functionality, and user experience; that's the reason why most of Magento store owners are planning for their upgrade now. In the Magento migration process, we will have to migrate theme, code, data, and extensions. In [this post](https://dev.to/tigren5/how-to-migrate-extension-from-magento-1-to-2-2n1), I will give you some facts and useful advice to migrate extensions from Magento 1 to 2.

Comment: if you are a developer, this advise is irrelevant.