# Can I use magento 2.0 module at magento 1.9?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

There is a similar question is asked [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90636/can-i-still-use-magento-1-9-module-theme-at-magento-2-0)

But here I am asking other way around. Can I use magento 2.0 module at magento 1.9?

Comment: It's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 architecture completely different from Magento 1, so we can't simply copy and paste the extension.

In M1

> app/code/local or community pool to carry all the custom extensions.

but in M2

> app/code/

will carry our custom extensions.

There is an file structural changes as well like namespaces and module structure also differs from each other.
Take a look at this
[Magento 2 Extension Development devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)